# what should be used instead of 'host.docker.internal' when using nerdctl in place of docker?

Tags: docker, localhost, containerd, nerdctl

When using docker desktop, we would connect to the host machine from the container using the URL 'host.docker.internal'.

however container is not able to connect to the host machine (i.e my machine) when I am using [nerdctl](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl) instead of docker.

I installed Rancher desktop to use nerdctl

Comment: Can you please tell, how you solved the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17981939/natesh-todur had solved it in our project, I don't remember exactly the solution now

Answer (score 2):

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

The above command will give the IP address of your wireless connection. Note, this will only work for MacOS. This IP can then be written to the /etc/hosts of your container against `host.docker.internal` as they share the same network. This can help the container communicate to the host machine by using `host.dock.internal` . Although, an elegant solution is expected from RancherDesktop (or its already available in the newer versions).

Comment: Thanks Natesh and Akshay. Natesh I'm assuming you used dockerd only..right?

Comment: dockerd (moby) as the container runtime.

Answer (score 1):

From lima docs.

> The loopback addresses of the host is 192.168.5.2 and is accessible
> from the guest as host.lima.internal.

So instead of `host.docker.internal`, provide `192.168.5.2`

I have tested this with nerdctl distributed via Rancher and it works!

reference: https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/blob/master/docs/network.md