# Rancher Desktop dockerd alternative for host.docker.internal

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, docker-desktop, moby, rancher-desktop

I am using Rancher Desktop with dockerd(moby)

When I use docker desktop, I can connect to the host machine from the container using `host.docker.internal`

But while using Rancher Desktop, `host.docker.internal` is not pointing to the localhost(I'm trying to connect to postgres database on my localhost).
I have also tried `--network=host` but I'm not able to curl to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, provided I had a frontend running on 8080.

What should be the alternative `host.docker.internal` for Rancher Desktop with dockerd(moby) ?

I have tried quite a few answers but none has helped me. I know this question has been asked but any help would be really appreciative.

Comment: you might find your solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231309/17981939

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you may need to create a firewall rule to allow communication between the host and the container. You can run below command in a privileged powershell to create the firewall rule.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Action All
```

Pls refer here

https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/faq/#q-can-containers-reach-back-to-host-services-via-hostdockerinternal